# How to send real-time data to a page loaded in UIWebView from iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, uiwebview, xamarin

I've built a web page that shows a map along with geo-tagged images. I would like to also show some real-time sensor data, for example noise levels.

I can put the page in a UIWebView in iOS and I can access the sensors I need from a native app (built in Xamarin if that's relevant).

I can obviously build web services on my server and send the sensory data from the native app, then use ajax to get the data to the web page. While there are good reasons to do this I would still like my app to continue working (albeit with decreased functionality) while it's not connected to the internet - I need to be able to pass the sensory data (json) from the native app to the web page without reloading the web view itself.

**Q:** Is there a way to continuously pass data from the native app to the page inside the UIWebView?

Comment: For the offline issue, you could use the pattern PhoneGap uses: have html/js files in device, and just use the server to consume webservices

Comment: Thank you, Edgar. I've considered that option and it remains somewhat viable but I would prefer to reuse existing code (C#, some ObjC) where possible, especially when it comes to dealing with already finicky sensors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this Xamarin Component

> Allows for bidirectional communication with the UIWebView in
>   Monotouch.

http://components.xamarin.com/view/jsbridge

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the bridge for Xamarin (and WP8) here: https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/tree/master/Core/SimplyMobile.Web

Take a look at the WebHybrid class (it has partial class implementation for Android, iOS & WP8 in addition to the core partial class).

Here is a small sample application: https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/tree/master/iOS/Tests/WebClientTests

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I wish I could mark two answers as correct. I will keep the library in mind as it seems to have plenty of useful features. I'm choosing the other answer only because it was simpler

Comment: jsbridge is a good library and it works. I decided to implement my own because I wanted the functionality for Android and Windows Phone as well. I also have several different JSON serializers to choose from in my libraries while jsbridge integrates a JSON serializer. There is quite a bit difference between JSON serialization and deserialization speeds and if you are planning to do lots of communication between the UIWebView and your application this will have an impact on the responsiveness.

Comment: I suspect I will end up using your library in the very near future, I do appreciate your efforts very highly, thank you!